# autostart vlc player on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

Im just learning and have very little experience with linux. I been trying to find a video or instructions for dummies on how to do this. Ive edited the config file a few times with no luck. Any help would be great. Im using raspberry pi 4 and using 2 projectors that are showing the same thing to my house. Please help.

Comment: Please take the time to explain what you want to achieve, what *exactly* you tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: What autostart mean? How to start VLC on boot up?